# I want my JavaScript on my php/html website to update live and instantaneously

Tags: javascript, php, html, live, instant

This might sound a bit dumb, but how did they get the slider : http://demosthenes.info/blog/757/Playing-With-The-HTML5-range-Slider-Input#volume

That number (%) updates instantaneously to the movement of your mouse when you slide the dot.

I was wondering for my own 'learning purposes' how that is possible since with the same code that they provide on my website, it won't work...

;)
Thnx!

UPDATE

My code:

```
<label for=fader>Volume</label>
    <input type=range min=0 max=100 value=50 id=fader step=1 onchange="outputUpdate(value)">
    <output for=fader id=volume>50%</output>
    </output>
    <script>
        function outputUpdate(vol) {
            document.querySelector('#volume').value = vol+"%";
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: You probably made a mistake? Provide your code so we can tell.

Comment: PHP's not involved; that's all client side.

Comment: @Joost: To improve your question, and in particular to add code, use the "edit" link, not comments.

Comment: Ah, yes, you need to change `onchange` to `oninput` they don't use what they tell you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
 <html>
 <label for=fader>Volume</label>
 <input type=range min=0 max=100 value=50 id=fader step=1 oninput="outputUpdate(value)">
 <output for=fader id=volume>50%</output> 
 <script> 
    function outputUpdate(vol) { 
       document.querySelector('#volume').value = vol+"%"; }
 </script>
 </html>
```

You need to change `onchange` to `oninput`, they don't use what they tell you.

Comment: Thanks @KIKOSoftware . Thank you for the quick help. I will accept the answer in a minute!

Comment: You're welcome. I have noticed the code on that site (the link you gave) is not of very high quality. Be aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

> That number (%) updates instantaneously to the movement of your mouse when you slide the dot.

There's this event called `mousemove`. Probably has something to do with it.

For instance:

```js
document.querySelector(".slider").addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  document.querySelector("#position").innerHTML =
    e.pageX + "x" + e.pageY;
});
```

```css
.slider {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">Move your mouse over this div</div>
<div id="position"></div>
```

Comment: I think it is the `onchange` event in this case.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware: *" instantaneously to the movement of your mouse when you slide the dot"* doesn't sound like it. I didn't follow the link; I work on the basis of the information ***in*** the question.

Comment: The code shown in that blog post definitely claims to work via the "change" event, but (Firefox anyway) won't fire the "change" event continuously.

Comment: No, the author says one thing 'onchange' and do something else 'oninput'. 'mousemove' could work as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is [HTML5 range element](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_range.asp) with registered mousemove event on it. Something like:

```
$('input').on('mousemove', function() {
    $('.foo').text($(this).val());
});
```

Look at jsfiddle for better understanding: http://jsfiddle.net/a7ztqz10/

Answer (score 0):

The onchange event fires when you release the mouse, to update as the value changes they have used the oninput event handler.
By inspecting the element and looking at the event listeners you can see that it is using oninput

```js
function outputUpdate(vol) {
document.querySelector('#volume').value = vol;
}
```

```html
<label for=fader>Volume</label>
<input type=range min=0 max=100 value=50 id=fader step=1 oninput="outputUpdate(value)">
<output for=fader id=volume>50</output>
```